# How can I add array values to a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using the following code to sort MySQL queries into time/date:

```
mysql_select_db("user_live_now", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_newest_post ORDER BY users_date_post DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      print($row['user']);
  }
```

instead of having the PHP run through and show all the values in the table can I have it show the values from an array?

Comment: You mean show only specific users?

Comment: Then build the SQL query in such a way as to return only those users you are interested in. Look up syntax similar to `SELECT ... WHERE user IN ('foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: I think your social network will crash if you continue using `SELECT *` like this.

Comment: haha how'd u know I was building a social network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to find specific users in the SQL query to return?  Build your query programmatically:

```
$users = array('User1','John','Pete Allport','etc');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users_newest_post` WHERE ";
$i = 1;
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $sql .= "`username` = '$user'";
    if($i != count($users))
    {
         $sql .= " OR ";
    }
    $i++;
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY `users_date_post` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Which would get you a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `users_newest_post` 
WHERE `username` = 'User1' 
OR `username` = 'John' 
OR `username` = 'Pete Allport' 
OR `username` = 'etc' 
ORDER BY `users_date_post` 
DESC
```

So, you want to find all posts for a certain date or between two dates, kinda hard to do it without knowing the table structure, but you'd do it with something like this:

```
//Here's how to find all posts for a single date for all users
$date = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);  
//You'd pull the timestamp/date in from a form on another page or where ever
//Like a calendar with links on the days which have posts and pass the day 
//selected through $_GET like page.php?date=1302115769
//timestamps are in UNIX timestamp format, such as you'd get from time() or strtotime()
//Note that, without a timestamp parameter passed to date() it uses the current time() instead

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `users_date_post` = '$date'"
$results = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    echo $row['post_name'] . $row['users_date_post']; //output something from the posts
}

//Here's how to find all posts for a range of dates
$startdate = date('Y-m-d',$starttimestamp);
$enddate = date('Y-m-d',$endtimestamp);
//Yet again, date ranges need to be pulled in from somewhere, like $_GET or a POSTed form.
//Can also just pull in a formatted date rather than a timestamp and use it straight up instead, rather than going through date()
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `users_date_post` BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";

//could also do:
//"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `users_date_post` > '$startdate' AND `users_date_post` < '$endate'"

$results = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    //output data
}
```

To find posts for a specific user you would modify the statement to be something like:

```
$userid = 5;  //Pulled in from form or $_GET or whatever
"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `users_date_post` > '$startdate' AND `users_date_post` < '$enddate' AND `userid` = $userid"
```

Comment: What if I needed all of those values?

Comment: How do you mean?  Which values?

Comment: All of them: John, Pete Allport, etc, I am trying to pull the user's friends from a table of all users if that makes sense?

Comment: How is the table structured so that you know who the user's friends are?

Comment: haha I can't tell you that but I'm going to try and implement your example with some of my pages and see how it works as long as I can use all of those

Comment: Well, all I need to know is it like `userid` `frienduserids` where `userid` is an int corresponding to their id in the user table and frienduserids is a comma separated list of ids corresponding to their ids in the user table, so you'd have `userid` 1 and `friendids` 5,23,65,58 or is it like `userid` `friendid` where you'd have `userid` 1 `friendid` 5, `userid` 1, `friendid` 23, etc. etc. if so you can do it with a single SQL statement like `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userid = $userid`

Comment: Well yeah there are other rows like `user_new_post` and I was just trying to figure out how to print($user) and the `$row['user_new_post']` maybe this is similar to what your talking about

Comment: ughh yeah I just started teach myself this today bu I just tried `WHERE user_date_post = $user_date_post` and that didn't work when I tried to print it out... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you'd need a specific date in the format of the `user_date_post` column.  If it was a DATE type in MySQL (format YYYY-MM-DD) then you'd need to do something like: `$user_date_post = "2011-03-15";` or `$user_date_post = date(Y-m-d,$timestamp);` but MySQL is pretty forgiving about date format.

Comment: yes it is, as I've found out, how could I then print out the `user_date_post` with the code you gave me?

Comment: Instead of using the `BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'` is there a way to use an array of users

Comment: That goes back to the original answer I gave.

Comment: Well maybe this will help you: I have a table `user_newest_post` and in the table I have the following rows: `user_full_name`, `user_new_post`, `user_username`, and `user_date_post` in the table I will be storing every user the creates an account. From the "master" list I want to pull out specific users. That is what I ment by an array. I hope this clears things up

Comment: Then you'll have to do a WHERE clause on user_username like: `SELECT * FROM user_newest_post WHERE user_username = 'username1' OR user_username = 'username2' OR etc etc etc`

Answer (score 0):

To dump the result into an array do the following:

```
mysql_select_db("user_live_now", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_newest_post ORDER BY users_date_post DESC");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $newarray[]=$row
}
```

Comment: No no, This is good except I need to be able to be able to load an array into the query, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is this:

```
$users = array("Pete", "Jon", "Steffi"); 

$users = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $users);
$users = implode(",", $users);

..("SELECT * FROM users_newest_post WHERE FIND_IN_SET(user, '$users')");
```

The [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://search.mysql.com/search/query/search?group=refman-55&q=FIND_IN_SET) function is a but inefficient for this purpose. But you could transition to an `IN` clause with a bit more typing if there's a real need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users_newest_post` WHERE username IN (' . implode(',', $users) . ')';
```